# Pattern matching characters for svn:ignore

Tags: svn

Making echo of a question around the web:

> Is the syntax for svn:ignore patterns
>   documented somewhere? The only pattern
>   matching character I could find in the
>   SVN book under 'svn:ignore' is '*'.

[Subversion Book: 'svn:ignore'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3)

In particular I want to match a 32 character string (md5 hash named directory).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be documented [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.ignore).

Edit: ...and to answer your specific question, you can use "?" to match a single character.

Comment: It says "File pattern matching is a bit more complex than what we've described here, but this basic usage level tends to suit the majority of Subversion users." Is that really a complete list?

Answer (score 3):

From what I saw at the page you linked and the [Ignoring files via cvsignore](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/cvsignore.html) page, it looks like it understand only glob syntax, ie. * for any string and ? for a character.

If you need to match a 32 character string, a possible solution might be to put 32 ? signs together...