# svn-ignore everything except certain folders

Tags: svn

Is it possible to ignore all the contents of a folder except for a specific sub folder in a svn-ignore pattern?

Ive read that you can negate a substring using ! But i can't get this  *[!dir/] to work.

Comment: Not possible as far as I know (extglob patterns don't seem to work) but I may be wrong. Once you add a dir it's of course no longer ignored though, so if it's just one.....

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @Wrikken. Now that I know it's not possible I will look at restructuring my project so that the ignored folders are not mixed with non - ignored folders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using svn:ignore to ignore everything but certain files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137761/using-svnignore-to-ignore-everything-but-certain-files)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you should negate a character instead of string. For example, if you want to ignore all folder except "abc" and "def", the ignore pattern should be like this:

```
[!a&!d]*
a[!b]*
ab[!c]*
d[!e]*
de[!f]*
```

- 1st line ignore anything not start with "a" and "d".
- 2nd line ignore anything start with "a" but not start with "ab".
- 3rd line ignore anything start with "ab" but not start with "abc".
- 4th line ignore anything start with "d" but not start with "de".
- 5th line ignore anything start with "de" but not start with "def".